# migrate mysql DB between two servers using replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, master-slave-replication

I need to perform some steps, I have to migrate our company live DB to a new server, if I use normal way such as lock table, mysqldump, scp, mysql restore, it take around 5-6 hours, so I want to make it quicker by those steps:
( note that i already have master/slave replication on backup server )

1- take full mysql backup from backup server and write down pos.

2- restore backup from previous step in the new DB server.

3- create master/slave replication between old & new Live DB from pos I took from step 1.

4- lock write on Live DB.

5- ensure that new Live DB are up to date (how to ?).

6- publish new Live DB server.

so steps from 1 to 3 take whatever it take but my Live DB still working, and i will take around 1/2 an hour between steps from 4 to 6, is my theory working well ?, any suggestion ?
also how to ensure that my new Live DB are up to date, i think like when there is no one write on master db (by lock write on DB) the current pos Counter on slave db stop counting..?

Answer (score 0):

If you *already* have LVM set up on the disk subsystem use it.  Else, see:

[MYSQL DATABASE BACKUP](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161708/mysql-database-backup/161886#161886)
[How can I optimize a mysqldump of a large database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database/2853#2853)
https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/08/21/using-lvm-for-mysql-backup-and-replication-setup/